# Can´t post comments, have pagination issues - assume Database Probs due to migration from Dev to Production

Tags: database, pagination, comments

In my DEV-envoronment I can post comments and pagination works. On my production machine not.
I assume, that I did something wrong, when I used phpMyAdmin to dump the Dev-DB and then uploaded the DB into my Production Server.

I checked around and changed the paths in the Production-DB manually. But I have to admit, since I did this for the first time, that it was a laborious proccess. I saved the templates as files and ftp´ed them onto the Production Server, I moved the DB with phpMyAdmin and then - as mentioned - I went through the CP on the Production-Server to set the paths.

Not very clever, I admit, but now I´m stumped. I turned debuigging on, but I can´t see any issues.

Which tools can I use to figure out, why the comments aren´t posted to the DB. I checked with phpMyAdmin: When I post a comment nothing gets added to the DB.

Regarding the pagination: This code works on my Dev-machine:

```
{paginate}
Seite {current_page} von {total_pages} | blättern: {pagination_links}
{/paginate}
```

But on the Production machine EE is not executing this code while rendering the page, but just "prints" it out, so that it´s there like a text string.

Comment: What kind of server are you running on now?

Comment: Shared hosting, a unix machine with Apache 1.3x modules 
    mod_ssl
    mod_auth_mysql
    mod_include
    mod_rewrite PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: I'd start by making sure you've uploaded everything correctly, files, database, the lot. The not posting of comments could be down to a .htaccess issue.